# How do i create a horizontal collage using only HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css, image

How do I create the horizontal collage and with the same space in between pictures (shown in the picture below) using html5 and css3?

I am very new into both StackOverflow, HTML5 and CSS3 so I do apologize if this post is a bit messy. And I hope you can help my anyway.

This is how i want the final design to look.

Here is my code so far:

```css
    h1 {
    font-family: 'Brother 1816 Bold', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a71b1a;
    }

    h2 {
    font-family: 'Brother 1816 Bold Italic', Arial, Helvetica, 
    sans-serif;;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    }

    .collage_index_1 {
    align-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/tck7grc.css">
    <title>Freya Photos - Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    <header>
      <!-- all the code related to the header here -->
    </header>

    <h1> <center>WELCOME TO FREYAS PHOTOS!</center></h1>
    <h2> <center>We are where you are, helping you capture the moments of life.</center></h2>

    <!-- I cannot align these three images here: -->

    <div class="collage_index_group">
      <div class="collage_index_1">
        <img src="img/optimized images/adorable-20374_1920_250x250.png" alt="Image in black and white of a very young child laying on his stomach underneath a white towel.">
      </div>
     
      <div class="collage_index_2">
        <img src="img/optimized images/bride-1867228_1920._250x250png.png" alt="A summer picture of a woman and a man standing amongst very high reed and kissing eachother passionately">
      </div>

      <div class="collage_index_3">
        <img src="img/optimized images/smile-2072908_1920_250x250.png" alt="A portrait of a young woman holding an apple in her right hand, close to the face while looking straight into the camera, with a little smile">
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <!-- all the code related to the footer here -->
    </footer>
  </main>
  
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: The image you are trying to share does not appear. Have you done some research before posting your question?

Comment: read a good book on CSS layout possibilities

Comment: @TheBlindHawk It shows to me perfectly, you might need to click on the hyperlinked text to show it.  I have done research for over 3 days but havent got my head wrapped around it yet.

Comment: Have you tried putting down some code?

Comment: have you tried anything yet ?  did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: here is a good tutorial site for beginners [link](https://www.w3schools.com/). Please put down some code we can have a look at.

Comment: @PontusYdström Refer this link for CSS flexbox when you will have good knowledge of HTML along with CSS: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Also add a design reference (if you have) while asking theming related question, so that others can understand the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to have a look at `display: flex` [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)
Here is an example.

```css
/* the flex container */
.collage_index_group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* the flex items */
.collage_index {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1> <center>WELCOME TO FREYAS PHOTOS!</center></h1>
<h2> <center>We are where you are, helping you capture the moments of life.</center></h2>
<div class="collage_index_group">
  <div class="collage_index">
    <img src="img/optimized images/adorable-20374_1920_250x250.png">
  </div>
 
  <div class="collage_index">
    <img src="img/optimized images/bride-1867228_1920._250x250png.png">
  </div>

  <div class="collage_index">
    <img src="img/optimized images/smile-2072908_1920_250x250.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for sharing the code, please do not forget to share the css. If you could make a snipplet with it it would be perfect ;) 
I will now try to adjust my snipplet accordingly.

##### Edit

I mistakenly wrote something about h1-h6, but found out I was wrong after double checking.

Comment: @Thanks! Will dive deeper to get a bigger understanding of CSS Flexbox. Thanks for patience and help

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that what you mean

```css
/* HORIZONTAL SCROLL */
.scroll-container{
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px 70px 5px 20px;
  background: transparent;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius:15px;
}

.scroll{
  display:inline-block;
}

.scroll img {
  margin-right:22px;
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  width:33%;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center; font-style:italic;">Scroll to left</div>
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="scroll">
    <!-- PLACE YOUR IMG URL HERE -->
      <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/programmer-working-with-program-code-picture-id1075599562?k=20&m=1075599562&s=612x612&w=0&h=cDFY2kKyhFzSNNlDQsaxoekIW0v7iyaMBkxp11Fz33U="/>
      <img src="https://www.careergirls.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Computer_Programmer1920X10180.jpg"/>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzayYFmglnoDZ2RifRciFtyiRGEXBHiMZClL06Ul5RYslak48IW9kKxSDB9-_g9954-vM&usqp=CAU"/>
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzayYFmglnoDZ2RifRciFtyiRGEXBHiMZClL06Ul5RYslak48IW9kKxSDB9-_g9954-vM&usqp=CAU"/>
              <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzayYFmglnoDZ2RifRciFtyiRGEXBHiMZClL06Ul5RYslak48IW9kKxSDB9-_g9954-vM&usqp=CAU"/>
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzayYFmglnoDZ2RifRciFtyiRGEXBHiMZClL06Ul5RYslak48IW9kKxSDB9-_g9954-vM&usqp=CAU"/>
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSzayYFmglnoDZ2RifRciFtyiRGEXBHiMZClL06Ul5RYslak48IW9kKxSDB9-_g9954-vM&usqp=CAU"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, its kind of what i want. However i only want to show the three pictures on the same line. I want them to be horizontally center aligned under my H1 and H2.. They should not be clickable. And they should not need a horizontal scrollbar to show them. They should fit next to eachother with the same amount of space to the left of the first picture and to the right of the last one. , and the space inbetween should be uniform as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).